# Move files from one directory to another if they appear in a text file in Python (take 2)

Tags: python, move, directory

Ok I'm going to try this again, apologies for my poor effort in my pervious question.

I am writing a program in Java and I wanted to move some files from one directory to another based on whether they appear in a list. I could do it manually but there a thousands of files in the directory so it would be an arduous task and I need to repeat it several times! I tried to do it in Java but because I am using Java it appears I cannot use java.nio, and I am not allowed to use external libraries.

So I have tried to write something in python.

```
import os
import shutil

with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print myNames

dir_src = "trainfile"
dir_dst = "train" 
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    print file  # testing
    src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
    shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

"files.txt" is in the format:

```
a.txt
edfs.txt
fdgdsf.txt
```

and so on.

So at the moment it is moving everything from train to `trainfile`, but I need to only move files if the are in the `myNames` list.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether the file name exists in the myNames list 
put it before shutil.move

```
if file in myNames:
```

Answer (score 0):

> so at the moment it is moving everything from train to trainfile, but ii need to only move files if the are in the myName list

You can translate that "if they are in the myName list" directly from English to Python:

```
if file in myNames:
    shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

And that's it.

However, you probably want a *set* of names, rather than a *list*. It makes more conceptual sense. It's also more efficient, although the speed of looking things up in a list will probably be negligible compared to the cost of copying files around. Anyway, to do that, you need to change one more line:

```
myNames = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

And then you're done.

Comment: @user3084959: You need to upgrade to Python 2.7 or later. If you can't, just do `myNames = set(line.strip() for line in f)`. If that doesn't work, you need to upgrade to 2.4 or later, or add an `import sets` and change to `myNames = sets.Set([line.strip() for line in f])`. If _that_ doesn't work, you need to upgrade to 2.3 or later, or install a third-party set package, or use the same trick (a `dict` whose values are all `True`) as in `perl`.

Comment: Or, of course, you could just use a list instead of a set, with the caveats mentioned in the answer (feels clumsier, runs slower).